# Azure ForEach activity failing with: The function 'length' expects its parameter to be an array or a string. The provided value is of type 'Integer'

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

How do I convert my value to an integer?

Here's added context if helpful:
My pipeline should get the column count of a blob CSV and pass that count to a ForEach activity. A switch activity is embedded in ForEach, but the pipeline is failing at ForEach with this error: 'The function 'length' expects its parameter to be an array or a string. The provided value is of type 'Integer'.

Metadata output:

```
{
    "columnCount": 52,
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime (Central US)",
    "executionDuration": 1,
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 0
    },
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "PipelineActivity",
        "billableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "AzureIR",
                "duration": 0.016666666666666666,
                "unit": "Hours"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

ForEach input:

```
{
    "items": "@activity('Get Metadata1').output.columnCount",
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "Switch1",
            "type": "Switch",
            "dependsOn": [],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "on": "@item()",
                "cases": [
                    {
                        "value": "44",
                        "activities": [
                            {
                                "name": "Copy data1_copy1",
                                "type": "Copy",
                                "dependsOn": [],
                                "policy": {
                                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                    "retry": 0,
                                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                    "secureOutput": false,
                                    "secureInput": false
                                },
                                "userProperties": [],
                                "typeProperties": {
                                    "source": {
                                        "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                                        "storeSettings": {
                                            "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                                            "recursive": false,
                                            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                        },
                                        "formatSettings": {
                                            "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "sink": {
                                        "type": "AzureSqlSink",
                                        "writeBehavior": "insert",
                                        "sqlWriterUseTableLock": false
                                    },
                                    "enableStaging": false,
                                    "translator": {
                                        "type": "TabularTranslator",
                                        "typeConversion": true,
                                        "typeConversionSettings": {
                                            "allowDataTruncation": true,
                                            "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "inputs": [
                                    {
                                        "referenceName": "ten_eighty_split_CSV",
                                        "type": "DatasetReference",
                                        "parameters": {
                                            "FileName": "@pipeline().parameters.SourceFile"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "outputs": [
                                    {
                                        "referenceName": "ten_eighty_split_10_15_SQL",
                                        "type": "DatasetReference",
                                        "parameters": {}
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "52",
                        "activities": [
                            {
                                "name": "Copy data2_copy1",
                                "type": "Copy",
                                "dependsOn": [],
                                "policy": {
                                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                    "retry": 0,
                                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                    "secureOutput": false,
                                    "secureInput": false
                                },
                                "userProperties": [],
                                "typeProperties": {
                                    "source": {
                                        "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                                        "storeSettings": {
                                            "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                                            "recursive": false,
                                            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                        },
                                        "formatSettings": {
                                            "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "sink": {
                                        "type": "AzureSqlSink",
                                        "writeBehavior": "insert",
                                        "sqlWriterUseTableLock": false
                                    },
                                    "enableStaging": false,
                                    "translator": {
                                        "type": "TabularTranslator",
                                        "typeConversion": true,
                                        "typeConversionSettings": {
                                            "allowDataTruncation": true,
                                            "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "inputs": [
                                    {
                                        "referenceName": "ten_eighty_split_CSV",
                                        "type": "DatasetReference",
                                        "parameters": {
                                            "FileName": "@pipeline().parameters.SourceFile"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "outputs": [
                                    {
                                        "referenceName": "ten_eighty_split_15_20_SQL",
                                        "type": "DatasetReference",
                                        "parameters": {}
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "60",
                        "activities": [
                            {
                                "name": "Copy data3_copy1",
                                "type": "Copy",
                                "dependsOn": [],
                                "policy": {
                                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                    "retry": 0,
                                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                    "secureOutput": false,
                                    "secureInput": false
                                },
                                "userProperties": [],
                                "typeProperties": {
                                    "source": {
                                        "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                                        "storeSettings": {
                                            "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                                            "recursive": false,
                                            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                        },
                                        "formatSettings": {
                                            "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "sink": {
                                        "type": "AzureSqlSink",
                                        "writeBehavior": "insert",
                                        "sqlWriterUseTableLock": false
                                    },
                                    "enableStaging": false,
                                    "translator": {
                                        "type": "TabularTranslator",
                                        "typeConversion": true,
                                        "typeConversionSettings": {
                                            "allowDataTruncation": true,
                                            "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "inputs": [
                                    {
                                        "referenceName": "ten_eighty_split_CSV",
                                        "type": "DatasetReference",
                                        "parameters": {
                                            "FileName": "@pipeline().parameters.SourceFile"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "outputs": [
                                    {
                                        "referenceName": "ten_eighty_split_25_30_SQL",
                                        "type": "DatasetReference",
                                        "parameters": {}
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "68",
                        "activities": [
                            {
                                "name": "Copy data4_copy1",
                                "type": "Copy",
                                "dependsOn": [],
                                "policy": {
                                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                    "retry": 0,
                                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                    "secureOutput": false,
                                    "secureInput": false
                                },
                                "userProperties": [],
                                "typeProperties": {
                                    "source": {
                                        "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                                        "storeSettings": {
                                            "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                                            "recursive": false,
                                            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                        },
                                        "formatSettings": {
                                            "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "sink": {
                                        "type": "AzureSqlSink",
                                        "writeBehavior": "insert",
                                        "sqlWriterUseTableLock": false
                                    },
                                    "enableStaging": false,
                                    "translator": {
                                        "type": "TabularTranslator",
                                        "typeConversion": true,
                                        "typeConversionSettings": {
                                            "allowDataTruncation": true,
                                            "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "inputs": [
                                    {
                                        "referenceName": "ten_eighty_split_CSV",
                                        "type": "DatasetReference",
                                        "parameters": {
                                            "FileName": "@pipeline().parameters.SourceFile"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "outputs": [
                                    {
                                        "referenceName": "ten_eighty_split_30_35_SQL",
                                        "type": "DatasetReference",
                                        "parameters": {}
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

ForEach output:
`{}`

Not sure how to satisfy this error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Failure type: User configuration issue
> Details: The function 'length' expects its parameter to be an array or a string. The provided value is of type 'Integer'.

Since you use an integer value (**columnCount**) as an input to for-each activity, you are getting this error. If you have array of values and you want to iterate the activity based on each value of array, you can use for-each activity. In this case, you can use the **switch case activity** directly after **get metadata activity**.  In Switch activity, expression is given within braces `{...}` .

**Expression:**
`@{activity('Get Metadata1').output.columnCount}`

I tried this in my environment and got the same error when I give the expression **without braces {..}**. When {} are added, it worked. Below are the steps.

- **Get MetaData activity** is taken and **column count** is taken as an argument.

**Output of MetaData activity**:

```
{
    "columnCount": 2,
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime (West US)",
    "executionDuration": 1,
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 0
    },
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "PipelineActivity",
        "billableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "AzureIR",
                "duration": 0.016666666666666666,
                "unit": "Hours"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

- Then Switch activity is taken and expression and case are given.
  Expression:  `@{activity('Get Metadata1').output.columnCount}`

[image]

- When pipeline is debugged, it got executed successfully without error.